# How can I change object property values as local storage values change?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, if-statement, local-storage

I want to change the `bt.name_en`, `bt.text_en` and `bt.date_en` as the LocalStorage (`const local = localStorage.getItem("inLan");`) changes.

If the `const local (const local = localStorage.getItem("inLan");` is equal to `name_jp`, then the name, text and date change to "JP" (`bt.name_jp`, `bt.text_jp` and `bt.date_jp`) as well. How can I do this effectively and correctly?

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <Header />
      <div class="line">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="bt in list" :key="bt.id">
            <div class="line-cont">
              <h2 class="dateX" >{{ bt.date_en }}</h2>
              <h1>{{ bt.name_en }}</h1>
              <p>{{ bt.text_en }}</p>
              <div class="divm">
                <img class="img" :src="bt.image" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { l } from "@/modules/languages";
import useAb from "@/modules/About";
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer.vue";

export default {
  name: "About",
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  setup() {
    const cards = useAb();
    const list = computed(() => cards.state.abouts);
    const local = localStorage.getItem("inLan");

    return {
      l,
      list,
      local,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you implement localization wrong way, you can refer `vue-i18n` or this: https://cli.vuejs.org/dev-guide/ui-localization.html#translate-the-standard-ui

Comment: I'm using something of my own and created internally. Without vue-i18n

Comment: ok, first get the language code from local storage, assume name it as `langCode` and then change from `{{ bt.date_en }}` to `{{ bt["date_" + langCode }}`